# Pandas Jupyter Notebook - value_counts of a column in relation to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-wrangling

I am a Beginner with Pandas and really don´t know how to solve this problem:

I have a df that looks e.g. like this:

```
A             B        C
process a   xawdw      0
process a   wdqwdqf    0
process a   wqwrq      0
process b   rwqrqw     2
process b   rwrwr      1
process c   qrqrw      1
process c   qrrwr      2
process c   rt544z     3
process d   zrz4z4z    0
process e   zrzrz45z4  0
process e   7zkzuk     0
```

Columns A and B are important for me. There are processes that consist of 3, 2 or 1 process_instances. For me, only the ones that consist of 3 or 2 are important (like a,b,c,e) and where all values in column C for each instance is 0.

Goal: I need to know how many processes are value 0 (columns C). But keep in mind that one process might consist of 3 or 2 process_instances. In this case only process a and e are important for me and goal is to give me out something like this:

```
Instances.   Total number of only 0-processes
3 instances: 1 (#process a)
2 instances: 1 (#process e)
```

I tried `value_counts` - however it will only return the total number of 0s in colums C. But I need the total number of processes where the value in colums c is zero in all instances of a process.

Answer (score 2):

You can test all groups if containsonly `0` values, chain with test if duplicated `A` and pass to [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
m1 = ~df.A.isin(df.loc[df['C'].ne(0), 'A'])
#alternative
#m1 = df.C.eq(0).groupby(df.A).transform('all')
m2 = df.A.duplicated(keep=False)

s = df.loc[m1 & m2, 'A'].value_counts()

print (s)
process a    3
process e    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Last if need count values again:

```
print (s.value_counts().rename_axis('Instances').reset_index(name='Total number of only 0-processes'))
   Instances  Total number of only 0-processes
0          2                                 1
1          3                                 1
```

Comment: @Dilan What means Not working? Can you be more specific what is difference between output of my solution and expected output?